# Missing records for a running sum using window functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, cumulative-sum

| Account | date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 20230501 | 10 |
| X2 | 20230501 | 11 |
| X3 | 20230501 | 12 |
| X1 | 20230502 | 20 |
| X3 | 20230502 | 21 |
| X1 | 20230503 | 30 |
| X4 | 20230503 | 10 |

I want to retrieve a running total of "*Amount*" using windows function to get the following output:

| Account | date | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 20230501 | 10 |
| X2 | 20230501 | 11 |
| X3 | 20230501 | 12 |
| X1 | 20230502 | 30 |
| X2 | 20230502 | 11 |
| X3 | 20230502 | 33 |
| X1 | 20230503 | 60 |
| X2 | 20230503 | 11 |
| X3 | 20230503 | 33 |
| X4 | 20230503 | 10 |

I've tried the following SQL approach:

```
SELECT Account,  
       Date,  
       SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY Date) AS RunningTotal
FROM tab1;
```

But it does not provide data as above. How do I get output as above to show data for accounts which are no longer as of latest date?

Comment: if you have a calendar table, it's easy to extend the data, the tricky part here is you want all accounts to extends to some arbitrary date, usually you just fill the "holes". If you search here, there are lot of questions about how to fill data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example, similar to @lemon answer.  Added checking for first date for Account. Without full calendar.

```
with AccDates as(
  select  Account, min(date) minDate
  from tab1
  group by account
)
,Dates as( select distinct date from tab1)

select a.Account
  ,d.date
  ,sum(t.Amount)over(partition by a.Account order by d.Date) RunningTotal
from AccDates a 
left join Dates d on  d.date>=a.minDate
left join tab1 t on t.Account=a.Account and t.date=d.date
order by d.date,a.account
;
```

Result

| Account | date | RunningTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 2023-05-01 | 10 |
| X2 | 2023-05-01 | 11 |
| X3 | 2023-05-01 | 12 |
| X1 | 2023-05-02 | 30 |
| X2 | 2023-05-02 | 11 |
| X3 | 2023-05-02 | 33 |
| X1 | 2023-05-03 | 60 |
| X2 | 2023-05-03 | 11 |
| X3 | 2023-05-03 | 33 |
| X4 | 2023-05-03 | 10 |

Comment: this solution allows date holes if on a date there's no values registration

Comment: Yes, solution allow date holes. @user3376169 did not indicate this and his test data does not allow us to determine his needs.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way of addressing this problem is to:

- select all possible accounts from your table
- generate a calendar table in range (minimum_date, maximum_date) belonging to your table dates
- cross join all possible accounts with all possible dates, then left join this to your table, and fire your running sum

```
WITH cte_accounts AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT Account FROM tab
), cte_dates AS (
    SELECT MIN(Date) AS date_val, MAX(Date) AS last_date_val FROM tab
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_val), last_date_VAL FROM cte_dates WHERE last_date_val > date_val 
)
SELECT a.Account,  
       d.date_val,  
       SUM(tab.Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Account ORDER BY d.date_val) AS RunningTotal
FROM       cte_accounts a
CROSS JOIN cte_dates    d
LEFT JOIN tab 
       ON tab.Account = a.Account
      AND tab.date = d.date_val
ORDER BY d.date_val, a.Account
```

**Output**

| Account | date_val | RunningTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 2023-05-01 | 10 |
| X2 | 2023-05-01 | 11 |
| X3 | 2023-05-01 | 12 |
| X4 | 2023-05-01 | null |
| X1 | 2023-05-02 | 30 |
| X2 | 2023-05-02 | 11 |
| X3 | 2023-05-02 | 33 |
| X4 | 2023-05-02 | null |
| X1 | 2023-05-03 | 60 |
| X2 | 2023-05-03 | 11 |
| X3 | 2023-05-03 | 33 |
| X4 | 2023-05-03 | 10 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pCtFQZ1Y).

The last `ORDER BY` clause is not necessary: it's just for visualization purposes. On a side note, if you do mind about having the null values, you can filter them out in a subquery.

Comment: Do windows functions treat null differently with sum()? I see that X4 goes from Null to 10 on day 3, although "adding null to 10" would (I expect) be null.

Comment: That's an interesting point. I don't know the answer to this, but I've noticed this behaviour with practise. Probably there's something related to default frame specification values and how these work together with how window function compute values.

Comment: Ah right. I'm forgetting my basic T-SQL. Sum() always ignores nulls, in both analytic and aggregate functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql